# Pass by reference method

Tags: c, pointers, numbers

The question is to find twin prime numbers using pass by reference. I tried to code it out but it doesn't work the way normal pointers would? (Cannot use malloc function)

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int twinp(int *n)  
{  
  int i=2;  
  for (i=2; i<= *n/2; i++)  
  {  
    if (*n%i == 0)  
    return 0;  
    }  
  if (i > *n/2)  
  return 1;  
}  
int main ()  
{  
  int i, c= 0; 
  printf("Twin prime numbers before 100 are: ");
  for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++)  
  {  
    if (twinp(&i) && twinp(&i+2))  
    {  
      printf ("(%d, %d) ", i, i+2);  
      c++;
    }  
  }  
  printf (" \nTotal number of twin prime pairs: %d", c);       return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the reference to a function in c, you have to use pointers.
Use the '&' keyword to reference the address of the value. Remember to have a memory location at moment to pass the reference, so you have to store the 'i+2' in local function and pass the reference to your function. Then use '*' to access the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int twinp(int * n)  
{  
  int i=2;  
  for (i=2; i<= *n/2; i++)  
  {  
    if (*n%i == 0)  
    return 0;  
    }  
  if (i > *n / 2)  
  return 1;  
}  

int main ()  
{  
  int i, c= 0; 
  printf("Twin prime numbers before 100 are: ");
  for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++)  
  {  
    int i_plus_2 = i+2;
    if (twinp(&i) && twinp(&i_plus_2))  
    {  
      printf ("(%d, %d) ", i, i+2);  
      c++;
    }  
  }  
  printf (" \nTotal number of twin prime pairs: %d\n", c);       return 0;  
}
```

Comment: As in the question, the `twinp()` function doesn't always return a value.  That's bad!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. When you pass by reference, you pass a memory location `&` of a variable in the calling function (`twinp(..)`) and in the actual function implementation, you'd catch that memory location via `*` pointer. When you actually try to use the value, you have to make sure you deference with the `*`.

Another approach you can take would be the below:

In the function itself, we do our checks for that current number `AND` the `+2` number.

Your loop in your `main` function will take care of all the iterations up to `100`.

If we find the number is prime, we print in the function. If not, we return and continue to the next iteration in our `main` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
void twinp(int *n)  
{   
  for(int i= 2; i < *n; i++) {
    if((*(n) % i) == 0 || (*(n) + 2) % i == 0)
      return;
  }
  
  printf("(%d, %d),", *n,*n +2);
} 

int main ()  
{  
  int i, c = 0; 
  printf("Twin prime numbers before 100 are: ");
  for (i = 3; i < 100; i++)  
  {  
      twinp(&i);
  }  
  printf (" \nTotal number of twin prime pairs: %d", c);       
  return 0;  
}
```